# How is it possible that a WPF context menu is displayed outside the window?

Tags: wpf, windows

As I understand it, controls in WPF applications are not bound to system "window" resources (e.g., you can't find an handle for them with Spy++), unlike the old Windows Forms applications.

So, how is that possible that part of those menus can be displayed **outside** the parent window? **Why aren't they cut as soon as they reach the window borders?**

One possibility, of course, is that they aren't really WPF menus but, instead, standard Windows resources. That, however, collides with the fact that I can style one of those menus exactly like any other WPF control, and some quick look at the system messages log seems to confirm that as far as Windows knows **they are, in fact, the same exact resource** with the same exact handle.

Then, I went further. I applied a rotation to the menu:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type ContextMenu}">
    <Setter Property="RenderTransformOrigin" Value="0.5,0.5" />
    <Setter Property="RenderTransform">
        <Setter.Value>
            <TransformGroup>
                <ScaleTransform/>
                <SkewTransform/>
                <RotateTransform Angle="-18.435"/>
                <TranslateTransform/>
            </TransformGroup>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

And this is the rather interesting result:

[image: Menu gets clipped in a rectangle]

So, what's going on?

Comment: FYI: This is applicable to a combobox as well when expanded.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you search on net for WPF context menu, you will find lots of articles stating **`ContextMenu` doesn't belong to same Visual Tree as that of its parent**.

They are not part of actual window, they are hosted in separate window. Just like you can have multiple windows in WPF over each other. Same holds true for ContextMenu and Popup's.

ContextMenu is a Popup only instead. If you are interested in looking at actual class responsible for handling it is `System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.Popup` class present in `PresentationFramework.dll`. Method `CreateWindow` gets called whenever context menu is opened.

And on close `DestroyWindow` method gets called to destroy the popUp window created to host content of ContextMenu.

So, whenever a context menu is opened/closed under the wraps a window is created and destroyed which is obviously not a part of main window but a separate window altogether which can go outside main window boundaries.

Answer (score 4):

> but, instead, standard Windows resources

Which is indeed what they are, a standard Windows window.  Just like your main Window.  A top-level window, they can arbitrarily overlap other windows.

But you can see the consequences, an *air-space issue*, a native Windows window cannot be rotated.  It is a basic rectangle, it at best can be given a shape.  Which could be a shape that is calculated by rotating the rectangle, but WPF doesn't take it that far.  Only the *content* can be rotated.  Which is easy to do in WPF, content is simply layers of paint, not a native window like they are in Winforms so rotating it merely requires a rotate transform.  But of course can't extend beyond the confines of the native window.

Answer (score 3):

The `Popup` object is a base for any "floating" context over a normal `Window`, such as context menus, drop-down lists, etc.

In fact, the `Popup` instance creates a secondary Win32 Window, which is targeted to host the desired WPF content. In fact, the `Popup` class leverages the HwndSource interop:

[MSDN: HwndSource Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.interop.hwndsource%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

This is also useful:

[Win32 Handle (HWND) & WPF Objects](http://www.abhisheksur.com/2010/12/win32-handle-hwnd-wpf-objects-note.html)